# Print element title in email

Tags: 8, webforms

Given the following element in my webform, how do I print *Name: Fred* in my email?

```
Title   Key   Value
Name    name  Fred
```

I understand how to print the raw value. How do I print the title?

```
[?]: [webform_submission:values:name:raw]
```

An admin may change the element's title, so I can't have *Name: [webform_submission:values:name:raw]*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a webform's element properties including #title, #description via tokens is not currently supported. I am not sure the core Webform module should provide these tokens, but a third-party module can easily make these tokens available.

Comment: Yes, for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use a Twig template. I have an if statement so that the label and colon are omitted if the element is left empty.

```
{% if data.name %}
  {{ elements.name['#title'] }}: {{ data.name }}
{% endif %}
```